# Spring UTF-8 hebrew support

Tags: spring, utf-8

I have come a cross a problem with hebrew letters and UTF-8 which I need some help to clarify.

Our webapp is using spring mvc 2.5.6 and is currently supporting utf-8 charecters in input fields - such as danish letters æøå and some hebrew letters like ר and ס. However, not all hebrew characters are supported. E.g if i use the search string like רעננה it is "translated" to רעננ�? when submitted. Clearly, the ה is not supported!

The characterset encoding is set using  spring characterencoding filter like:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

And as it is obviuos, it is working for some characters. What is needed to make it support all hebrew charaters?

Comment: The search term is btw submitted as a url-parameter, and in the url, it looks just fine. It is extracted in Java using:
new String(ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request,"searchString","").getBytes(), "UTF-8");

If you need anything else, just ask! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Instead of using java's new String(bytes, encoding), I use javascript's encodeURIComponent(string) of the searchString before setting the request parameter. In java the term is decoded using URLDecode.decode(String, Encoding), which works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

what server are you using? For example by default, Tomcat uses ISO-8859-1 character encoding when decoding URLs received from a browser, which you can customize in the server.xml by

```
<Connector port="8090" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

even if you are not using tomcat the same issue might happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It did however not help me in anyway - although I think, it probably is a good idea as well.
I looked further into the issue, and the parameters are actually not "posted" - that is, there is no submit. The page is just a javascript redirect with the correct parameters set in the URL (no encoding done). It is then in a spring AbsctractController pulled from the request an interpreted - this is where it all goes wrong. Even with URI encoding set. Any ideas?